# Magnitude and distribution of largest prime factor?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples, square-free

[Erdos-Kac law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem) state a typical number of magnitude $n$ has $\log\log n$ prime factors.

> 1. What is magnitude and distribution of largest prime factor of typical magnitude $n$ natural number?
> 2. What is magnitude and distribution of largest and second largest prime factor of typical magnitude $n$ natural number given than there is a prime factor $p|n$ of size $n^{0.25\pm\epsilon}$?

Assume $\epsilon\in(0,0.25)$ is fixed.

> I am also interested in 1. and 2. for square-free scenario.

Comment: I'm no number theorist nor analyst, but my back-of-the-envelope calculation suggests that as long as $\alpha \leq 1$ is not too small, the probability that all prime factors of $n$ are $\leq n^\alpha$ should be about $\alpha$.

Comment: @TimCampion It might be a good heuristic. Mind elaborating?

Comment: Assuming that the events $p \mid n$ are independent for different primes, we want to calculate ($p$ ranging over primes) $\prod_{n^\alpha \leq p \leq n} (1-1/p) = \exp(\sum_{n^\alpha \leq p \leq n} \log(1-1/p)) \approx \exp(\int_{n^\alpha}^n (dx/\log x) \log(1-1/x))$. Keeping only the first (!) term of the Taylor expansion for $\log(1-1/x)$, $\alpha$ is the result, as long as I haven't made an elementary calculus mistake (which I wouldn't discount!). Even if one accepts the integral approximation, the Taylor approximation may well be losing a $\log \alpha$ factor or something.

Comment: Isn't this some kind of proof? So the independence assumption is invalid?

Comment: What? No, there is no sense whatsoever in which this is a proof of anything. The independence assumption doesn't even literally make sense, since there's not really such a thing as "the probability that $n$ is prime".

Comment: That is correct we just work with random models

Comment: @TimCampion:  That guess is very much off base.  The chance that a number $n$ has all prime factors below $n^{1/u}$ is given by the Dickman-de Bruijn function $\rho(u)$, which for large $u$ is about $u^{-u(1+o(1))}$.  Thus this is very different from $1/u$ which the naive heuristic would suggest.  The same story holds for the distribution of lengths of cycles in a random permutation.  Google "smooth numbers".